# How to place cls in Comma seperated values

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6

I am placing emptyText by using

`abc.inputEl.set({'placeholder':rec});`

where `abc` is my `tagfield` and `rec` is comma seperated value.

eg : rec = "A,B,C"

So after applying this emptyText in tagfield is coming "A;B;C". No I wanted to add some cls. like underline in ABC. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add cls on placeholder because placeHolder is an attribute of inputEl. If You want to add Cls on inputEl then you can by using this:

```
listeners:{
          afterrender:function(combo){
              var me = this,
              values = me.getValueRecords();
              me.inputEl.set( {
              'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Hello'});
              me.inputEl.set({'style':'background:red;text-decoration:underline;'});
          },
          change:function(tag){
              window.r = this;
              console.log(this);
              var me = this,
              values = me.getValueRecords();
              me.inputEl.set( {
              'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Hello'});
          }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Got it, but I don't want background. I want to underline which is not working and instead of comma I want ";"

Comment: Thanks I will try with css